# ArrayOfObjects cannot be cast to Java.util.Collection

Tags: java, collections, casting

I tried googeling this for several hours with all different approaches.

Here the code in Java which calls a Web Service method in ASP .Net C#

```
public DefaultTableModel SelectAllProjects ()
{
    try{
    DefaultTableModel DtM;
    Collection c = (Collection)wws.selectAllProjects();
    Iterator iter = c.iterator();
    DtM = new DefaultTableModel();

    DtM.addColumn("Project ID:");
    DtM.addColumn("Project Name:");
    DtM.addColumn("Project Description:");

    Vector vec = new Vector(c.size());

    while(iter.hasNext()){

        Project p = new Project();
        p.getPId();
        p.getPName();
        p.getPDescript();
        vec.add(p);
        DtM.addRow(vec);

    }

    return DtM;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

And here's the webservice method...

```
[WebMethod]//Ska vara collection
public List<Project> SelectAllProjects()
{
    Controller contr = new Controller();
    List<Project> project = contr.SelectAllProjects();
    return project;
}
```

I know that method is working because a Windows Forms Application written i C# can successfully call it.

I also know the connection between Java and Web Services work since I can call the other methods.

My Catch(Exception e) returns the following message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javaapp.ArrayOfProject cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
```

Thanks for the answers, couldn't find anything close.

P.s. Tried `Object[] obj = (Object[])wws.selectAllProjects();`
and `Project[] proj = (Project [])wws.selectAllProjects();`

**Request for the Auto-generated ArrayOfProject.java class**

```
package javaapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import java.util.*;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArrayOfProject", propOrder = { "project" })
public class ArrayOfProject {
    @XmlElement(name = "Project", nillable = true)
    protected List<Project> project;

    public List<Project> getProject() {
        if (project == null) {
            project = new ArrayList<Project>();
        }
        return this.project;
    }
}
```

Code From my view class.. (The button I press)

```
private void btnAllProjects_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try{
    Controller control = new Controller();
    DefaultTableModel DtM;
    DtM = control.SelectAllProjects();
    JTable selectProjectsTable = new JTable (DtM);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}
```

List of my latest Exceptions:

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\bin\javaw.exe -client -classpath "C:\Users\MS\Desktop\Web Services\Java Uppgift 2\.adf;C:\Users\MS\Desktop\Web Services\Java Uppgift 2\JavaApp\classes;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrf.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\com.oracle.toplink_1.0.0.0_11-1-1-5-0.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\org.eclipse.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\com.bea.core.antlr.runtime_2.7.7.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-0-0.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.xdk_11.1.0\xmlparserv2.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.xdk_11.1.0\xml.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.nlsrtl_11.1.0\orai18n-mapping.jar" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\MS\AppData\Local\Temp\trustStore7859653733656575754.jks javaapp.Main
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2760)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2734)
    at java.util.Vector.ensureCapacityHelper(Vector.java:226)
    at java.util.Vector.insertElementAt(Vector.java:554)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.insertRow(DefaultTableModel.java:357)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.addRow(DefaultTableModel.java:333)
    at javaapp.Controller.SelectAllProjects(Controller.java:56)
    at javaapp.View.btnAllProjects_actionPerformed(View.java:103)
    at javaapp.View.access$200(View.java:24)
    at javaapp.View$3.actionPerformed(View.java:68)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6289)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6054)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:644)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
```

Comment: Can you post your ArrayOfProject class?

Comment: `SelectAllProjects()` method is actually returning DefaultTableModel. I am not sure where you are trying to convert it.

Comment: Added the extra code from that class. //T

Answer (score 1):

You need [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method to convert array to List i.e. Collection

Comment: Where shall I put this method?

Answer (score 0):

The class `javaapp.ArrayOfProject` needs to implement `Collection`

As an alternative you can create a wrapper which implements Collection.

The simplest is likely to be to create an ArrayList, copy all the elements and use the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that Arrays are not collections, there is a utility method on the `Arrays` class called `asList` which takes an array as an argument.

Comment: How shall I make an array of project then that works? This code is the single one that didn't generate an exception even before compiling.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayOfProject` is a class that your SOAP framework generated. It's just a regular Java class. Check what getters it has, depending on the framework used there'll be something that either returns an array or a list.

In your code edit this line:

```
Collection c = (Collection)wws.selectAllProjects();
```

to

```
Collection c = wws.selectAllProjects().getProject();
```

The rest will then work as-is.

Comment: Posted the code from that class, how shall I "Follow along as usual" :-) Thanks for the answer

Comment: You really don't see the getter of the list in there? Please, just look again. There is nothing else BUT the getter.

Comment: Ofc. I see It, but I've only done a couple of hours of programming in my life. However, I do not know how to use It in my controller.

Comment: Thanks for that :-) I tried doing that, but I now I get a list of exceptions after pressing the button. Although the program compiles without errors at first. I'm going to post the code from my view class aswell.

Comment: So please accept this answer as it answers your original question. Don't extend this question to the next problem you have, this is not how it works on SO.

Comment: Okey, I will not update anymore. I've not extended my problems rather added additional code that might be useful for the people trying to understand my problem.